# How to understand the proof of Proposition 2.1 in the paper 'Nodes and the Hodge conjecture'?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, hodge-theory, hilbert-schemes

In the Proposition 2.1 of the paper ['Nodes and the Hodge conjecture](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0212216)', R.P.THOMAS gives a proof to descending the Hodge conjecture into showing that every (n,n)-Hodge class in a $2n$-dimensional smooth projective complex variety is algebraic.

However, I can't understand the part of relative Hilbert scheme there. Since the Hilbert scheme there seems different from the usual one and I even can't find the definition. I am wondering if anyone could explain to me about this or provide to me with some proper references.

Comment: As far as I can tell, Grothendieck constructed the Hilbert Scheme in this generality. It's certainly done in the first chapter of Kollár's book on Rational Curves.

Answer (score 1):

As R.P.Thomas told me, the relative Hilbert scheme there is the usual one, and the section 4 of the paper *[A remark on singularities of primitive cohomology classes](https://www.baidu.com/link?url=OVopYvKMBziN44QFUWxv1p0fqaQ6QyMWPCzWCOmyJpN89lDxcfgu7XqUfBHQYt9o&wd=&eqid=956b420e005d9e81000000035d439b37)* gives a more explicit refinement.